# Translating Apache Camel example from Spring DSL to Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am trying to convert a Camel route in Spring DSL to its equivalent in Java DSL. I nailed most of the translations, but there is something I simply don't know how to do: to change the headers.

Here are the examples:

**Spring DSL:**

```
<bean id="service" class="org.apache.camel.example.service.Reporting" />
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="mina1">
        <from uri="mina:tcp://localhost:9991" />
        <setHeader headerName="minaServer">
            <constant>localhost:9991</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <bean ref="service" method="updateReport" />
        <to uri="direct:messageSender1" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

**Java DSL:**

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("mina:tcp://localhost:9991")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("localhost:9991"))
    .beanRef("camel_examples.loadbalancer_failover_javadsl.service.Reporting", "updateReport")
    .to("direct:messageSender1");
}
```

And finally, the bean method that uses the Header:

```
public Report updateReport(@Body Report report, @Header("minaServer") String name) {

    report.setReply("Report passed by MINA servers running on: " + name);
    return report;
}
```

Now, on the example using Spring DSL, everything works fine. But in the example using Java DSL, I am simply unable to set the headers correctly. it just does not happen. I know the reason for this is the line `.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("localhost:9991"))` , probably the `Exchange.HTTP_METHOD` part, but I do not know what to put there either to be honest. I also tried with `Exchange.HTTP_URI` and the result was the same.

What is wrong in my translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.exchange.getIn().setHeader("minaServer", constant("localhost:9991"))
```

Comment: You can't be serious ... but I will try :P

Comment: I joke about a lot of things. But I draw the line at joking about Camel. Haha I'm glad it worked out. Good luck with your project!